# Matching $END$ in perl

Tags: perl

When i use the line :

```
if (m/^$END$/g) { 
    # ...
}
```

in my code, the compiler thinks that I am searching for a Static'END$' in my code, 
whereas I want to search the string "$END$". How shall I go about it?

Comment: As written (and to a first approximation), that regex looks to see if the value that's in the variable `$END` matches the entire line in `$_`.  You need a backslash before the first `$` to prevent it being interpreted as the sigil at the start of a variable, and maybe another before the second `$` if that is not marking the end of line.  I did suggest `if (m/^\$END\$/gi)` in a comment to your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844918) (given that your original attempt there included the `/i` modifier as well as the `/g` modifier, which probably isn't really needed here).

Comment: Yes @JonathanLeffler Sir. 
Now does my question abide to the SSCCE format? :P

Comment: This question is excellent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Personally I found the phrase "the compiler (?) thinks (?) that I am searching for a Static(?)'END$'? in my code (?)" was pretty confusing. With question marks to mark the questionable parts.

Comment: Never use `if (/.../g)`. Aside from making no sense conceptually, it can result in odd, subtle, unexpected results.

Comment: @TLP: compared with the other one, this is excellent.  I'm not completely clear about the `Static'END$'` part, but it is a great improvement over asking for an analysis of over 300 lines of Perl in two scripts.

Comment: Not at all clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.  You say `I want to search the string "$END$"`; some seem to assume you want to search in `$_` for a literal `$END$`, perhaps only matching if it is found at the start.  That seems to be guessing several things not actually stated in your question.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match a literal `$`, just escape it with a backslash:

```
if (m/^\$END\$/) { ... }
```

Removed the `/g` that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/\A\Q $END$ /x) { ... }
```

[perldoc perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html):

> `\Q`  Disable pattern metacharacters until `\E`

Removed the `/g` that shouldn't be there.